# How to create a user voter to vote for one single choice in a poll in Django

Tags: python, django, database, orm

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    def _get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.question)
        unique_slug = slug
        num = 1
        while Poll.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, num)
            num += 1
        return unique_slug

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self._get_unique_slug()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pub_date',)


class Choices(models.Model):
    poll = models.OneToOneField(Poll, related_name='choices')
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    voter = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='voters', blank=True, null=True)
    vote_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.vote_count += 1
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        pass  #  order_with_respect_to = 'poll'
```

It doesn't allow user to vote more than one poll. and if I change it to `voter = models.Foriegnkey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='voters', blank=True, null=True)`
It allows users to vote more than a single option in a poll which is not the intended behaviour.
I will appreciate if I can't get help to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: What is `voter_count` exactly?

Comment: total number of votes per option(choice_text)

Comment: but now that means that for *each* voter you will store the total? It is a bit strange that the option is "bound" to the `voter`...

Comment: So should I bound the entire choice model to a foreign key of voter(new model)

Comment: I think it makes more sense that you have a `Poll`, an `Option`, and `Vote` yes.

Comment: class ChoiceVotes(models.Model):
    choices = models.OneToOneField(Choices, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='choice_voters', blank=True, null=True)
    vote_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

Comment: Maybe the voter field should be `unique`: `voter = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='voters', blank=True, null=True, unique=True)`